# how to use index of numpy.array in numba.njit()?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numba

how to use index of numpy.array in numba.njit()? In the following, if numba.njit is used, the code will exit with an error. I find that the error dues to "b = a[idx]". But in fact, that should be right in python. How to correct that in numba? thx

```
@numba.njit()
def test(a):
    idx = np.where(a>5)
    b   = a[idx]
    return b

a = np.linspace(0,15,16).reshape([4,4])
b = test(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#array-access) say that *a subset of advanced indexing is also supported: only one advanced index is allowed, and it has to be a one-dimensional array*.

And if you run your code without numba, you can see that the result is an 1D array anyway:

```
>>> a[np.where(a > 5)]
array([ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15.])
```

So you can operate on an 1D array directly:

```
@nb.njit()
def test(a):
    a = a.ravel()
    idx = np.where(a > 5)
    b = a[idx]
    return b
```

Or even simpler:

```
@nb.njit()
def test(a):
    a = a.ravel()
    return a[a > 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this documentation

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/arrays.html

b = test(a)

try to change the variable here like

k=test(a), as I think test(a) = b and that would mean like b=b

just try if it works ...